# Exporting/restoring Multiple SSIS DTSx packages to file system

Tags: sql-server, migration, ssis

Is there a way to export and import multiple dtsx packages from SQL Server 2008?

I'm trying to find a built-in way/free tool/script to automate right-clicking the package, selecting "File System" for package location, and specifying the same server and package path for about 50+ packages.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at **[DTUTIL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162820.aspx)**

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at SQLServer Powershell Extensions (SQLPSX)?  There is a library of functions for doing just this kind of thing.

http://sqlpsx.codeplex.com/